# Jpg file to gcode conversion in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Can anyone please help me for converting a jpg file to gcode file using android studio . Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://opentinkers.com/tutorials/gcode_creation/

Answer (score 0):

But this is by using Inkskape. I want it to be done using Java code in android studio.coversion from jpg to gcode using java